# My PC starts up on keyboard input, even when told to shutdown

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown

I put my PC to sleep mode. I press any key on the keyboard to wake it up. The process works as expected.

My problem is when I shutdown my PC and press any key, it starts up. I am using Windows 8.1 & motherboard: gigabyte H61M-S2PV

I don't know why I'm getting this. If you need to know more information about my PC, please tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This most likely isn't an issue with Windows 8.1, but rather an option set in the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). The reason I say this is because such a functionality would need to be supported in the hardware as the OS isn't available to act until it has been loaded as part of the boot process.

The way to modify this setting depends on the specific motherboard that you use. The first set of instructions are a relatively generic set that should apply for most motherboards. If you are able to, check the user manual that came with your motherboard, as this should contain more information on this setting and how to change it.

- Restart your machine.
- While it's booting, it should tell you a key to press to access BIOS settings or BIOS Setup (it's usually one of the function keys at the top of your keyboard or <kbd>DEL</kbd>). As an example, on my machine it says `BIOS Setup: <DEL>` in the lower left of the screen during boot.
- While this screen is showing, press the specified key (it may be worth tapping it a few times to ensure that it registers). If you press it too late and it continues to load, just follow these instructions from the top again.
- In the menu that follows, look for a setting called something like "Boot from Keyboard", "Boot on key press" or "Power On By Keyboard" most likely in a menu called "Boot", "Advanced Settings", "Power Management Setup" or similar. This step is the hardest, as each motherboard will handle their own menu and naming systems differently. Again, check your motherboard manual for more information.
- If you find the option, turn it off.
- Save and exit (again, the way to do this depends on your motherboard, but it should specify the different exit options at the top or the bottom of the screen).

This should hopefully fix the issue with your machine booting by key press.

The following instructions apply specifically to the motherboard specified in the original post, which is a "Gigabyte H61M-S2PV". The instructions can be found in the [downloadable PDF of the user manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-h61m-s2pv_e.pdf), but I've simplified the instructions and included them below. Check the document if you require more information or would benefit from images ("Power Management Setup" details can be found at the end of Page 32, with more information on "Power On By Keyboard" being found at the end of Page 33).

- Restart your machine
- Press <kbd>DEL</kbd> when the logo/post screen appears (if in doubt, tab <kbd>DEL</kbd> until it loads the BIOS Setup menu).
- In the menu that appears, select "Power Management Setup"
- Go down to "Power On By Keyboard" and ensure that it is set to `[Disabled]` (it might also be worth checking that "Power On By Mouse" is also set to `[Disabled]`).
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save your changes, then press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I add the model of my motherboard.

Comment: @Mezbah I've added a set of instructions for your motherboard in particular.

Answer (score 2):

For some computers this can Not be done in the BIOS and must be done in Windows.

Steps for Windows 7/8/10:

1. Open *Keyboard Properties* window:

[image]

2. Go to *Hardware* tab and click button *Properties*
3. Click button *Change settings*
4. Go to tab *Power Management*
5. Disable *Allow this device to wake the computer*
   [image]

Note: you can disable wake up from mouse in a similar way. Just open Mouse Properties.